# Rename the public folder to public_html in laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-7

I use Laravel and Vuejs in my project.In my project, I changed the name of the public folder to public_html. When I run the "npm run watch" command, the public folder is created again, which is a problem for me.

in AppServiceProvider

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
   {
   /**
   * Register any application services.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function register()
   {
    $this->app->bind('path.public',function (){
        return base_path().'/public_html';
    });
   }

  /**
   * Bootstrap any application services.
   *
   * @return void
   */
   public function boot()
   {
    //
   }
 }
```

and in my server.php code:

```
<?php

/**
* Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
*
* @package  Laravel
* @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
*/

$uri = urldecode(
  parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);

 // This file allows us to emulate Apache's "mod_rewrite" functionality from the
// built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel 
// application without having installed a "real" web server software here.
 if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__ . '/public_html' . $uri)) {
  return false;
 }

 require_once __DIR__ . '/public_html/index.php';
```

and in webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

 /*
 |-------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build 
    steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

  mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public_html/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public_html/css');
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem so that the public folder is not re-created?

Comment: I think you'd need to check/post `webpack.mix.js`

Comment: I updated the webpack.mix.js file @brombeer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by calling `mix.setPublicPath("your-public-path")` in your webpack.mix.js